Using rsync to insert a new subdirectory
I have an existing remote file system like so:
├── freshmeat
│   └── prime
│       ├── A
│       └── B

I want to insert an update from a local directory:  freshmeat/prime/c/D
So the end result would be:
├── freshmeat
│   └── prime
│       ├── A
│       └── B
|       |___ C
             |- D  

I use rsync -rvzP freshmeat/prime/c/D freshmeat/prime --delete
This throws an error that the directory does not exist.  Why does it not work?

This isn't actually about programming, probably belongs on Unix and Linux Stack Exchange although check their site rules for whether your question is fully on-topic.

This post might be helpful, but to summarize you can use the --relative flag (like rsync -a --relative /C/D/ user@remote:/home/username/freshmeat/prime/) where everything part the period will be created.
